# How can I use android volley with oauth2?

Tags: java, android, rest, oauth-2.0, android-volley

I actually use volley to consume a web service but now this web-service changed to use oauth2.0, but I don't know how to implements this in the volley.
There is a way to use it directally or I need to create a token and then add the token to the headers of the volley?

```
String url = getString(R.string.api_url) + getString(R.string.Controller);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray objects = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) arrObject.add(gson.fromJson(objects.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ObjectDTO.class));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_object, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
);
SingletonRequest.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

I actually connect get a successfully with the web-service in the postman of google chrome with the same url and the followings parameters: AuthURL, AccessTokenURL, ClientID, ClientSecret, Scoope, GrantType.

Comment: I don't think that volley supports oauth natively. (It even doesn't support base authentication natively). So, you should implement it by providing your credential in the headers. It's not hard tho.

Comment: So I just need add the generated token in the header like string? I mean something like this:@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    String auth = "Bearer [StringToken]";
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
    return headers;
}